# Query multiple mysql rows and seperate into variables after?

Tags: php, mysql

I was just wondering if there is a better way to do the following code... I have a table that will never have more than 1000 rows and on average 300 rows.

```
$largeside_mysql = mysql_query("(SELECT url, image FROM advert WHERE placement = 'largeside' AND paid = 'complete' AND city = '{$GLOBALS['user_city']}' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT url, image FROM advert WHERE placement = 'largeside' AND paid = 'complete' AND province = '{$GLOBALS['user_province']}' 'city' != '{$GLOBALS['user_city']}' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT url, image FROM advert WHERE placement = 'largeside' AND paid = 'complete' AND 'province' != '{$GLOBALS['user_province']}' 'city' != '{$GLOBALS['user_city']}' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT url, image FROM advert WHERE user='1' AND uniqid='largeside' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
 LIMIT 3 ") or die(mysql_error());
    $GLOBALS['largeside'] = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($largeside_mysql)) {
    $GLOBALS['largeside'][] = $row;
    }
```

It took me a bit of reading but I have got this to work, basically it passes global variables for use during page load.

I want to count the rows found in one query then if the limit IS NOT reached do another query to add additional rows until the LIMIT is reached. Most of the time the first query will find enough rows but the odd time it will need to have some added.

I was wondering if this is the best solution for the table size and for what I need to do.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Building your SQL like that is wide open to SQL injection.  Google "SQL injection", and rewrite your query so it uses '?' placeholders instead.

Comment: IF your talking bout the globals I passed them through mysql escape and the variable comes from a background script not a form. If not that what part is open or should I be careful of... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$largeside_mysql = mysql_query("
select url, image
from
(
    SELECT url, image, 0 as n
    FROM advert 
    WHERE placement = 'largeside' AND paid = 'complete' AND city = '{$GLOBALS['user_city']}'

    UNION ALL
    SELECT url, image, 1 as n
    FROM advert 
    WHERE placement = 'largeside' AND paid = 'complete' AND province = '{$GLOBALS['user_province']}' 'city' != '{$GLOBALS['user_city']}'

    UNION ALL
    SELECT url, image, 2 as n
    FROM advert 
    WHERE placement = 'largeside' AND paid = 'complete' AND 'province' != '{$GLOBALS['user_province']}' 'city' != '{$GLOBALS['user_city']}'

    UNION ALL
    SELECT url, image, 3 as n
    FROM advert 
    WHERE user='1' AND uniqid='largeside'
)
order by n, rand()
LIMIT 3 "
) or die(mysql_error());
$GLOBALS['largeside'] = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($largeside_mysql)) {
$GLOBALS['largeside'][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, will this grab the first query and if there is 2 select those 2 then add 1 from the second or third query? As far as performance also, is this the best option? I was wondering if it would be possible to do this with IF statements... Either way I will try this out and thanks again I appreciate it.

Comment: _Thank you for the reply, will this grab the first query and if there is 2 select those 2 then add 1 from the second or third query?_ That was my intention. Test it.

Comment: Isn't an `AND` missing before `'city' != '{$GLOBALS['user_city']}'`?